# Error connecting to local db server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, centos, mariadb

I have the following code:

```
try { 
      $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname=stats;port='.$port, $un, $pw);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      WriteLog("Could not connect to database!\nError: ".$e->getMessage());
      exit;
    }

    try { 
      $db_conn2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=log', $un2, $pw2);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      WriteLog("Could not connect to database[2]!\nError: ".$e->getMessage());
      exit;
    }
```

It connects without errors to the first server (not local), but then it fails to connect to the local server. I get this error message:

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (||)

I'm running PHP v5.4.27

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: it didn't solve it. My .sock files location is the same in my.cnf and php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Changing from localhost to 127.0.0.1 seems to fix it. I'm not sure why